# javasmartcardIO - How to cancel read action between host and smart card when timeout occur?

Tags: javacard

I developed a host app by using Java Smart Card IO framework. Host app send a reading command to card and is waiting to receive response.
During this process, timeout occur (timeout value is defined by me).

I suppose reading process will be stop when timeout occur. My question is how to do this? 
-   Currently,the host app is connect to card by using basic channel. I tried to close this channel but I got exception  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close basic logical channel` 
-   I also tried to open a logical channel by calling `channel = card.openLogicalChannel();`, but when the host send reading command it receive SW `6D00` - Instruction code not support or invalid.
-   I also tried to disconnect terminal and card by calling `card.disconnect()`, but I got exception

```
javax.smartcardio.CardException: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
    at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(ChannelImpl.java:219)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.transmit(ChannelImpl.java:90)
    at ISO.ISO7816.readRecords(ISO7816.java:234)
    at javasmartcardio.UI.PTCMainFrame$9.run(PTCMainFrame.java:343)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: WINDOWS_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
    at sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardTransmit(Native Method)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(ChannelImpl.java:189)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to close this channel but I got exception 
>   `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close basic logical channel`

ISO/IEC 7816-4 Page 9:

*The basic channel shall be permanently available, i.e., it cannot be closed. Its channel number is zero.*

---

> I also tried to open a logical channel by calling `channel =
>   card.openLogicalChannel();`, but when the host send reading command it
>   receive SW `6D00 - Instruction code not support or invalid.`

I suppose that you receive `0x9000` for calling `openLogicalChannel()` method. If so, you must first select your applet on the logical channel and then sending READ command. To select you applet on the new logical channel that you want to send the READ command through, you simply specify the channel number in the low nibble of `CLA` section of SELECT APDU command. (i.e `0X A4 04 00 <AID Len> <AID>` instead of `00 A4 04 00 <AID Len> <AID>`- X is the logical channel number).

In the other way, selecting your applet on Basic channel and sending read command on another channel for same applet is not correct. When you open a logical channel using `Manage Channel` APDU command, the selected applet on that channel is the card's Default Selected applet (not the applet that you selected already).

---

About the exception I guess it is something related to your reader.

I suggest you:

1. Open a logical channel other than the basic logical channel
2. Select your applet on that logical channel.
3. Send read commands through that logical channel.
4. After timeout close this logical channel.
5. Jump to 1.

Comment: I modified my code to open logical channel 1, then send command `01 A4 04 00 05 F0 00 00 00 01` to select applet but I get `6E00` SW

Comment: @neo Well, I think you installed you applet as default selected applet and in the program of you applet you throw `6E00` as exception for all the APDU commands with `CLA != 00`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've changed source code of my applet and it work now. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Hi @Abraham, close channel does not seem a good solution. It seem the channel not close immediately, instead host still wait to receive "channel not support " message. Some time it take too long and affect others processes  such as update GUI or next reading executing. Do you have any suggestion to immediately  ignore  current reading process when timeout occur ?

Comment: @neo Unfortunately I have no idea. Doesn't your reader support pseudo APDUs related to the timeout? Did you find any solution?